# How to pass and receive data in url using ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 3, i am trying to pass and retrieve data from controller

like if the below is the url

`href="http://www.example.com/mycontroller/myaction/22"`

how do i receive value 22 in a controller and pass it on to view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do with learning how routing works in ASP.NET MVC. There are some great tutorials [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

But, based on your example, using the Default route that is added as part of the ASP.NET MVC project template, if you created the following action method on a controller named `MyController` you could receive your parameter:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int id){
    // do something with id
    ViewBag.SomeId = id; // can be accessed by calling ViewBag.SomeId on your view
    return View(id); // can be accessed via the Model property of your view
}
```

Before you dive into solving problems with ASP.NET MVC it's crucial to learn the fundamentals. If you're coming from ASP.NET web forms then it's quite a learning curve.

Comment: Razor refers to the view engine which has nothing to do with controllers, model binders and routing.  In a word, "yes", it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Read a good book or a series of introductory articles and blog posts on ASP.NET MVC 3 first. You'll be glad you did. MVC 3 is not easy to learn if you're from an ASP.NET background.

Comment: It is easy to learn, `especially` if you have any sort of web development background, but not if you jump into it head first.

Comment: If you have an ASP.NET background, you may expect ASP.NET MVC to work similarly -- with postbacks, web controls, viewstate etc. And that is entirely not the way it works.